# Regarding a property of Schwartz class.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, schwartz-space

Let $f\in\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^n),$ the Schwartz class. Is it true that the function $g$ defined on $\mathbb{R}_+=[0,\infty),$ by
$$g(r)=\int_{S^{n-1}} f(rw)d\sigma(w)   $$
also in Schwartz class $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R_+})?$

($d\sigma$ is the normalised surface measure of $S^{n-1}$)

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I tried to show that $r^kg(r)$ is bounded for any $k$. But could not add $w^k$ inside the integral as its modulus is always less 1. And I also don't understand how to work with $k$ and multi-indices $\alpha=(k_1,...k_n)$. (Actually only this property of $g$ will serve my purpose)

Comment: Sir now I get that for$x=rw$ we have $x^\alpha=r^{\sum\alpha}w^\alpha$

Comment: $$|r^kg(r)|=|\int_{S^{n-1}}r^kf(rw)d\sigma(w)|\leq \int_{S^{n-1}}|r^k w^{(k,0,...,0)}f(rw)|d\sigma(w)\leq\int_{S^{n-1}}|(rw)^{(k,0,...,0)}f(rw)|d\sigma(w)<\infty.$$

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murthy Sir is that correct?

Comment: I think the first inequality is false.

Comment: Why sir? $|w^{(k,0,...0)}|=1$

Comment: Why is $|w_1^{k}w_2^{0}...w_n^{0}|=1$?

Comment: Sorry, it was my mistake. I thought as $w\in S^{n-1}, $ 
we will also have $ w^\alpha\in S^{n-1}$. Sir how to attempt this problem?